# If MotionEvent time-out 90 sec how call method?

Tags: java, android, timeout, motionevent

My task is that if within 90 seconds no MotionEvent occurs, there are no clicks on the buttons, then a certain method is called. How can I call a method if within 90 seconds there is no action?

Comment: use an android scheduler to schedule your task in scheduler add your method call logic

Comment: @GaneshGudghe I will be very grateful for the sample code)

Answer (score 0):

There is a number of alternative ways to do this

Now currently it is running every 2 min change accordingly

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduleTaskExecutor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);

// This schedule a runnable task every 2 minutes
scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    doSomethingUseful();
  }
}, 0, 2, TimeUnit.MINUTES); // change accordingly
```

OR

```
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        yourfunction();
       handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
};

//Start
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
```